# Animating object using easingfunctions on multiple target properties

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, animation

so what iam trying to is simply aimating an object's position using easing function what happens is that one of the translations which is the X in the case just translates to the new position then the y gets animated after that over the duration i want both of x and y get animated simultaneously here is the code iam using

```
var tg = new TransformGroup();
                var translation = new TranslateTransform(target.X - Canvas.GetLeft(sender), target.Y - Canvas.GetTop(sender));
                var translationName = "myTranslation" + translation.GetHashCode();
                RegisterName(translationName, translation);
                tg.Children.Add(translation);
                sender.RenderTransform = tg;
                var animY = new DoubleAnimation(0, target.Y - Canvas.GetTop(sender), new Duration(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 1, 0)))
                {
                    EasingFunction = new PowerEase { EasingMode = EasingMode.EaseOut }

                };
                var animX = new DoubleAnimation(0, target.X - Canvas.GetLeft(sender), new Duration(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 1, 0)))
                {
                    EasingFunction = new PowerEase { EasingMode = EasingMode.EaseOut }
                };
                var s = new Storyboard();
                Storyboard.SetTargetName(s, translationName);
                Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(s, new PropertyPath("(0)", new DependencyProperty[] { TranslateTransform.YProperty, TranslateTransform.XProperty }));
                var storyboardName = "s" + s.GetHashCode();
                Resources.Add(storyboardName, s);

                s.Children.Add(animX);
                s.Children.Add(animY);

                s.Completed +=
                    (sndr, evtArgs) =>
                    {
                        Resources.Remove(storyboardName);
                        UnregisterName(translationName);
                    };
                s.Begin();
```

Comment: Any reason for not using xaml? I would recommend to give that a try, it will help develop better understanding of animation and might eventually solve the issue too.

Comment: well the thing is the animation is used on a dynamically made shapes and yes the shapes must be created dynamically if there is a way to use xaml to make the animation then attach it to the shape i would gladly do it since dynamically making storyboards is really stupid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set the property path on each of the double animations, not the storyboard. Also, the way you specify the `PropertyPath` is not correct. You can either pass in an existing instance of a dependency property or a string that describes a complex property path.

Another minor issue is that you create and register a name for the element to animate. You should consider if you really need to do this. I would advise to just use `Storyboard.SetTarget` instead of `Storyboard.SetTargetName`.

Have a look at this code:

```
private static void AnimateObject(Rectangle rectangle)
{
    var translateTransform = new TranslateTransform();
    rectangle.RenderTransform = translateTransform;

    var storyboard = new Storyboard();
    var xAnimation = new DoubleAnimation(0.0, 100.0, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500))
                     {
                         EasingFunction = new PowerEase()
                     };
    Storyboard.SetTarget(xAnimation, rectangle);
    Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(xAnimation, new PropertyPath("(Rectangle.RenderTransform).(TranslateTransform.X)"));

    var yAnimation = new DoubleAnimation(0.0, 50.0, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500))
                     {
                         EasingFunction = new PowerEase()
                     };
    Storyboard.SetTarget(yAnimation, rectangle);
    Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(yAnimation, new PropertyPath("(Rectangle.RenderTransform).(TranslateTransform.Y)"));

    storyboard.Children.Add(xAnimation);
    storyboard.Children.Add(yAnimation);

    storyboard.Begin();
}
```

In it,  I create the translate transform and add it as a render transform. Afterwards I create two animations and set the target and property path on them. I add both of them to the storyboard and start it. Because I used `Storyboard.SetTarget`, I do not need to clean up after the animation is completed.

I hope this helps. Feel free to ask if you have any questions.